# Function Delete Testing

Tags: php, mysql

The global variable level scope, I'm trying to implement a delete function, and inside the delete query a global variable replacing the table name, like the code below, but when I test before the user click 'delete' it's defined, but when after clicking the button, the variable is undefined.

The `$GLOBALS['$table']` is been filled by the user, in a different function, and when I echo the `$GLOBALS['$table']` first, it shows me the value, and it's fine.

```
<?php

function DeleteOption()
{
    include ('../CIEcon.php');

    echo "<form action= 'Delete.php'  method = 'post'>";
    echo $GLOBALS['$table'];
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['Id']) || $_POST['Id'] == 0) {
            echo "<h4>  please choose something to delete   </h4>";
            echo $GLOBALS['$table'] . "hmmmm";
        }
        else {
            $impid = implode("' , '", $_POST['Id']);
            $sqlDelete = "DELETE " . $GLOBALS['$table'] . " WHERE Id IN ('" . $impid . "')";
            $DeleteQuery = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sqlDelete) or die("Error : " . mysqli_error($dbCIE));
        }
    } // end of delete...
    else {
        echo "";
    }

    echo "</form >";
}; // End of Delete Function..
```

this is how the $Globle['table'] has been defined by the user

```
<?php
include('../CIEcon.php');

$GLOBALS['$table']="";




function DisplayOption(){
    include('../CIEcon.php');

echo '
            <form action= "Delete.php"  method = "post">
            <table width ="40%" cellpadding ="4" border="1" align="center" >

            <tr >
            <th style ="color: white; background-color: #f26822 ; " >     Select a Catagory To Delete From   </th>

            </tr>';

                echo "<tr>



             <td>". 

            "<select name = lists >
              <option name= nothing value= 0 selected >Choose a Catagory</option>
              <option name= nothing value= 1 >    Advertising     </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 2>    Fiscal          </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 3>    Food            </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 4>    Shopping        </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 5>    Rentals         </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 6>   Setting up       </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 7>    Performances    </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 8>  Registration/Ushering  </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 9>   Master of Ceremonies  </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 10>    Cleaning up   </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 11>    Others        </option>

             </select>"



              ." </td>


             </tr>";




             echo '

             </table>
             <br/>

             <div align="center">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
             <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
             <hr> <hr> 
             </div>


             </form>

             ';

///
};



function SelectOption(){
    include('../CIEcon.php');

///
             if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))  // second submit
                        {
                          $errorMessage = "";

                           if(($_POST['lists'])== 0)  // trying to get error if user don't choose.
                              {
                                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot to Choose !</li>";

                              }

                              $lists = $_POST['lists'];  // <-save info in variable based on user input 

                              if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
                              {
                                echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
                                echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
                                die();
                              } 

                            } // end of second submit 




                            switch($lists)
                            {
                                case '1':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table']  ="Advertising";
                                break;
                                case '2':
                                  $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Fiscal";
                                break;
                                case '3':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table']="Food";
                                break;
                                case '4':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Shopping";
                                break;
                                case '5':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Rentals";
                                break;
                                case '6':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="SettingUp";
                                break;
                                case '7':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Performances";
                                break;
                                case '8':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Registration";
                                break;
                                case '9':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="MasterOfCeremonies";
                                break;
                                 case '10':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Cleaning";
                                break;
                                 case '11':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table']="Others";
                                break;

                                default;
                                    echo 'Unsupported category';
                                break;
                            }



                if ($GLOBALS['$table'] != ""){

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $GLOBALS['$table']. "  ";
                             $result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

//trying this...
$_SESSION["tbl"] = $GLOBALS['$table'];

                  /// NOW DISPLAY ALL INFO FROM CHOSEN DATABASE...///

                            echo "
                            <form action= 'Delete.php'  method = 'post'>

                            <table cellpadding ='4' border='1' width='80%' align='center'>
                            <tr>

                            <th>Check </th>
                            <th>Job's Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th> No Students needed</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            </tr>";

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo "<br>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>";
                           // echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Table[]'  value='". $GLOBALS['$table'] ."' /> </td>";

                            echo "<td>" . $row['JobName'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['NoStudent'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                            }




                            echo "</table>";
                   /// END THE SEARCH HERE...........///

                            echo " <br>
                                <div align='center'>
                                <input type='reset' value='clear' > 

                                <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'>

                                </div>

                            </form>";




                            }  // End if !table=""; 


             } else {  }



///
};// end of function SelectOption
```

Comment: Where is *$GLOBALS['$table']* defined, and are you sure that code is executed again after the user submits the delete request?

Comment: $GLOBALS['$table']  is defined it the top of the page, and it's like this
$GLOBALS['$table'] ="";

when I echo $GLOBALS['$table']  before the delete request if it prints fine, but after the request, it won't work.. don't know why

Comment: Can you be more clear when the variable is not defined? At the first echo of it? Please still add the code of where you define it. It is important to verify. Add it in the question, not only in comments.

Comment: I attach the code sir, would u please look at it. ?

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like on one request the global variable is set, but on another separate request it is not. If that's the case, it's because global variables do not persist across requests, and you would have to store it somewhere.

Comment: yes sir, that's exactly the case.  what do u recommend ?

Comment: Store it in the database or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you were already trying with the concept of session variables. Here is how to do it:

At the very top of your PHP file, right below this line:

```
$GLOBALS['$table']="";
```

add this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['table'])) {
    $GLOBALS['$table'] = $_SESSION['table'];
}
// rest of your PHP code...
```

Then in the function *SelectOption*, right after this:

```
switch($lists)
{
...
}
```

add the following line:

```
$_SESSION['table'] = $GLOBALS['$table'];
```

This way you keep the selected table alive across requests.

I would urge you however, to rewrite your code and better separate the part where you output HTML from the part where you initialise variables and execute SQL. The better you separate these two, the easier it is to maintain your code.

Comment: Yeah, and do not use Globals as they are insecure and deprecated since forever

Comment: trincot I  can't thank u enough, one week I've been working on this page, ONE Week.. THANK U SO MUCH SIR...

Comment: mazedlx , yes sir, it's just trying to make it work for now, and I'll work on the security after/  :) thank u sir